# Как сделать словарь из запроса?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Есть таблица. Через sqlalchemy делаю `fetchall`

```
GLOBAL|Name | Age | Height
USER   ivan   20    170
USER   petr   25    180
```

Как на выходе получить

```
{
 'USER': {'name': 'ivan', 'age': 20, 'height': 170},
 'USER': {'name': 'petr', 'age': 25, 'height': 180}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать user.**table**.columns :

```
def get_model_dict(model):
    return dict((column.name, getattr(model, column.name)) 
                for column in model.__table__.columns)
```

Использование:

```
user = User()
get_model_dict(user)
```

Comment: А просто list[dict] как пихнуть ему?